# Problems with @@ROWCOUNT and DB check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I cant get this to work, can anybody help me out ?

i am trying to create an database check for which DB that i am on, and if thats checks out i want the sql to perform an update statement with a trasaction clause there only commits if afected rows matces my input ( expexted rows) else rollback

```
IF DB_NAME () = 'IDIT_PP2' -- Envirionment check
  -- update only if affected rows is equal to expected rows
  BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE P_POLICY
SET    [STATUS_ID] = 20
WHERE  ID = 1000001

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1 -- Affected Rows = expected Rows
  COMMIT TRAN
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRAN
```

i excpected this to result in 1 affected row (only one record  with ID = 1000001  ) but if i change this to fx.  ID in (1000001, 1000003) i would expect 2 affected rows but is still only getting one

Comment: Your first `IF` statement needs a `BEGIN..END` block as I doubt it does what you need without that. what is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P_POLICY WHERE ID in (1000001, 1000003)`?

Comment: Well how many rows in P_POLICY have an ID of 1000001? That sounds like it is the primary key. As such there would never be more than 1 in @@ROWCOUNT because you are only updating a single row.